# Confused on has_many through: and advantages over alternate pattern with class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this right now.

```
has_many :planes, -> { where approved: true },  class_name: 'UserPlane'
```

It kind of smells I suppose but it works and is easy to do.  I suppose the correct way would be to do something like this.

```
has_many :planes, through: :user_planes, source: :plane do
   def approved
     where('user_planes.approved = ?', true)
   end
end

has_many :user_planes
```

Since I only want the planes that are approved and I don't care about one that are not.  What are the advantages of doing the second way as opposed to the first.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two snippets will give you different results. First association will return you a set of `UserPlane` objects from database, while the second will return you a set of `Plane` objects. However you should be able to simplify your second version to:

```
has_many :user_planes, -> { where approved: true }
has_many :planes, through: :user_planes, source: :plane
```

Comment: Oh derp.  I totally missed that.  Thanks!